# nuxt.js - $(...).slider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jquery in nuxt.js, I added jquery in nuxt.config.js like this:

```
build: {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            '_': 'lodash'
        })
    ]
}
```

and then I used jquery code in  in my template and I put jquery code in mounted() to avoid "document is not defined" error:

```
mounted: () => {
    $("#volume").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 0,
        range: "min",
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            setVolume(ui.value / 100);
        }
    });
    ....
}
```

but when I run this, I get `$(...).slider is not a function` in browser. Is there anything special I should do to get it to work in nuxt.js?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat this comment seems not really helpfull to me..

Comment: @derHugo Yup agree :))

Comment: slider is not part of the jQuery project, but jQUeryUI...

Comment: @derHugo Marzie has not even made an effort to search. I made a search and found million results. https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin and https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/356

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I searched a lot :) Trust me I wouldn't ask it here if I'd found a result that explained it in nuxt.js. I'm using nuxt and none of the results were about it.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat if the answer is so obvious then go ahead and post it here so we all can take advantage of it

Comment: Hey @MarzieTajik, did you find solution to it? I'm also having same scenario. It would be really helpful and time saving for me.

Answer (score 0):

$().slider is a jQuery UI function. You also need to add `jquery-ui` to your project.

Comment: Thanks, I installed jquery-ui using npm install but I don't know how to get nuxt to know it.

Comment: I am not familiar with nuxt.js, but I think it's enough to just import it in your mail script like: `import "jquery-ui";`

Comment: If this leads to errors like `$ is not defined` put an `import "jquery";` in the line before.

Comment: I did it and still get "JQuery is not defined" . Before adding "import "jquery-ui"" i didn't get this error.

Comment: So, jQuery UI initialises with JQuery. You have to expose it as well in your nuxt.config.js: `'$': 'jquery', 'JQuery': 'jquery'`

Comment: I did this but I get the error: jQuery is not defined , I don't really know why. I added 'jQuery': 'jquery' in nuxt.config.js .

Comment: You have to take care of the cases! JQuery !== jQuery. Please check that.

Comment: This is what I did: 'jQuery': 'jquery', 'jquery': 'jquery', 'JQuery': 'jquery', :)) I don't know how else to put it.

Comment: and you put the `import "jquery";` before `import "jquery-ui";`?

Comment: Yup. Here's what I did: `import jquery from 'jquery'; import jqueryUI from 'jquery-ui';` and then export default starts.

Comment: hmm the only reason now I can think of is, that the ProvidePlugin does not work as expected. Can you try to remove it and define a rule instead? `module: {
  rules: [{
    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
    use: [{
      loader: 'expose-loader',
      options: 'jQuery'
    }, {
      loader: 'expose-loader',
      options: '$'
    }]
  }]
}`

Comment: Still the same... I honestly gave up on jquery-ui.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to post more code? It sadly hard to remote debug.